# What to do if the primary action is actually to confirm a cancellation?

Tags: forms, labels, modal-windows, actions

[image: Dialog asking for cancellation confirmation with two cancel buttons]

I'll ignore the fact that it isn't obvious what '20190927.6' is from the screenshot (it would be more obvious in the workflow context).

Obviously someone is following the pattern that the primary button should be labelled clearly as the effective outcome - in this case, clicking on the primary button should result in '20190927.6' being cancelled.

They've also included a secondary button which backs out of the process without making changes - labelled 'Cancel'.

Luckily, there's a design convention - so the blue button is probably the primary action, and the grey button is probably the secondary.

What would be a better way to label these buttons?

Given the 'are you sure' question, wouldn't Yes/No buttons be good enough in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's Material design guidelines advises against using `Yes/No` as action texts in alert dialogs.

> The action [...] indicates the outcome of the decision.
>
> Don’t use action text that fails to indicate what the selection will do. “Cancel” and “Delete” better indicate what will occur in this dialog.

https://material.io/components/dialogs/#alert-dialog

In this case I'd change the wording of the alert dialog but still keep the outcome clear: `Cancel job/Keep job`. This add words but makes the outcome more clear. In the same time wording of the title and message body should be changed to be in line with buttons.